# Android Studio on Surface Pro 3 : should I install JDK x86 or X64?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-6

I want to install Android Studio on my Microsoft Surface Pro 3. I wonder if I should install the x86 or x64 version of the JDK from the following page :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I saw that some guy had bugs with some JDK versions. I would like to be sure !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the OS obviously. I have 64 bit therefor x64 and haven't had any issues. Make sure you install Java first though. I had to, I am not sure if all/some come with it installed already but obviously nothing would work without it.